# VB.NET indexof not finding string()

Tags: list, search, indexing

Here is my code:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)        
'populate list with string values

Dim list2 As New List(Of String())

    For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1
        list2.Add({list.Item(i), "temp"})
    Next

    for x as integer = 0 to list.count
        Dim test1 = list2.indexof({list.item(x), "temp"}) '***this line is returning -1
    next
```

Although I can clearly see that list2 contains in its first index the strings:

"Garry" and "temp"

it refuses to return an index other than -1 when I search for an index containing:

{"Garry", "temp"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ended up restructuring my code as to avoid the problem -- all good now.

I am not sure as to why this wasn't working; if anybody comes looking for a solution.